# Can't find variable: $

Tags: lightning-aura-components, jquery, ios, locker-service, dom

I'm got this error in lightning while testing in an iPad (issue only occurs in iPad / iOS. All other os , desktop,tablet works fine).

My solution is locker service enabled. All the resources like jQuery, bootstrap are loaded in a separate component and injected into current view.

Everything works just fine in all the desktop browsers including Mac OS too. But only iPad throws this error.

```
Something has gone wrong. afterRender threw an error in 'markup://c:ccindex' [Can't find varible: $] Failing descriptor:{markup://c:ccindex}
```

Sample use case in code where jQuery is used under locker service:

```
var mainElem = cmp.find('accordion-div').getElement();
var openElem = $(mainElem).find( ".open" );
$(openElem).animate( { "width": "80px" }, 'slow' );
```

Comment: Did you ever use `jQuery.noConflict` anywhere?

Comment: This sounds like a timing issue - would you please elaborate on "All the resources like jQuery, bootstrap are loaded in a separate component and injected into current view."? Does the problem persist if you deactivate LS?

Comment: @AdrianLarson i haven't used jQuery.noConflict anywhere ...

Comment: @DougChasman Problem goes away when the locker service is deactivated. Problem is only appear for LockerService + IOS(iPad).  "All the resources like jQuery, bootstrap are loaded in a separate component and injected into current view."? ::-- Entire solution is divided to components. ex: for index page(Home page) it consist of sidebar.cmp, menu.cmp, footer.cmp , content.cmp etc. according to the hash change i change the content.cmp .all the JS & CSS resources are included in menu.cmp.

Comment: It's the injection I am asking about - it's considered best practice to have any component that needs a library include it directly with ltng:require to insure that it gets its dependencies satisfied. If you are handling this library loading in a different way how are you insuring that the code that needs $() is not running before it's guaranteed to be there? Btw there is a known issue with LS and ltng:require that causes it to not insure once and only one loading semantics (work in progress on that).

Comment: @DougChasman , Thanks for your reply. I had to remove jQuery to get rid of the issue. Yes i used ltng:require to load the library.